# Does the Advanced Class Guide exist in German?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, german

As said in the title, does the Advanced Class Guide for Pathfinder exist in German? If not, do the contents exist in German? As in the classes and especially feats?

Comment: I know it's kind of a short question, and probably the answer is "no", (I think I would have found it via google easiely if it existed), so I am mainly asking for the second part of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Official Release: September 2015

The German version of Pathfinder is created and published by Ulisses Spiele (who are also the current creators of The Dark Eye). A [list of all German Pathfinder Rulebooks](http://www.ulisses-spiele.de/sortiment/rollenspiele/pathfinder/produkte/) published by them can be found on their website.

[Ausbauregeln VI: Klassen](http://www.ulisses-spiele.de/sortiment/rollenspiele/pathfinder/produkte/1061/ausbauregeln-6-klassen/), the German version of the Advanced Class Guide is scheduled for release in september.

Apart from the official release, there is also the [German PRD](http://prd.5footstep.de/) (which is linked to by Ulisses). As far as I can tell, it contains the official Ulisses translated content (which they put under OGL to prevent ugly copyright issues). At this moment there are no references to the ACG at the moment.

---

That being said, with the ACG being mostly OGL content, fan-based translations are legal and might exist somewhere in the internet, such as alternative PRDs (which I don't know of). Though to be honest, I wouldn't expect anyone to put in the effort of translating the whole book (without pay), when the official translation is already being worked on.